# How to create s3 connection with empty region using aws-js-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ceph

I use ceph service in my company with empty region, so i can only create s3 connection without region.
Bug the aws-js-sdk  will specify the region to `us-east-1`, how can i ignore this?
It will shows error like `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND...`;

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const getS3Instance = () => new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: 'xxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
    endpoint: `...local`,
    sslEnabled: false,
    region: ''
});

try {
    const s3 = getS3Instance();
    const creatBucketRes = await s3.createBucket({ Bucket: `bucket-test` }).promise();
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set which region the bucket is located in,

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-northeast-2  '});
```

Reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html

Comment: thanks a lot. But I just want to use an empty region because we do not have the `region` notion

Comment: There is nothing like regionless in AWS. Almost Every resource is bound to region. You need to deal with region in code to say which region you are talking to. CloudFront is Global, even then to update your distribution settings you need to update via region.